# Bluealsa on Pi Zero can not be installed

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w, packages

I am trying to install bluealsa package but getting this error :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/libexec/bluetooth $ sudo apt-get install bluealsa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package bluealsa is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bluealsa' has no installation candidate
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/libexec/bluetooth $
```

And of course it is not installed :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/libexec/bluetooth $ sudo service bluealsa start
Failed to start bluealsa.service: Unit bluealsa.service not found.
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/libexec/bluetooth $ sudo service bluealsa status
Unit bluealsa.service could not be found.
```

How can I install this package on my Pi Zero ?

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/libexec/bluetooth $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: According to the following page Blue ALSA is not available in Bullseye. https://wiki.debian.org/Bluetooth/Alsa with it expected to be in the next release, Bookworm. The following guide on Setting up a Bluetooth Speaker from the command line on a raspberry Pi Zero W has always been good: https://gist.github.com/actuino/9548329d1bba6663a63886067af5e4cb

Comment: That's strange -- I've never used it but: `cat /etc/issue` ->
`Debian GNU/Linux 11` (this is a Pi 4 running 64-bit RpiOS bullseye) `apt search bluealsa` -> `bluealsa/now 0.13 arm64 [installed,local]` ... `which bluealsa` -> `/usr/bin/bluealsa` ... `bluealsa -V` (get version) -> `1.4.0`